# Silent Hill Downpour not saving

Tags: silent-hill-downpour

Apparently it's only happening to me. The game says it's saving but it doesn't save anything. I just tested 5 mins ago, my last save was 00:53:12 I loaded it, fought some monsters, used some aid kits, and then the game said it was saving, but it didn't save anything. I quit the game right after the "saving" message, then hit on continue, and it loaded that same save in 00:53:12, in which I hadn't killed the monster nor used the first aid kit.

This one was just to test it but the way I noticed was much more annoying. I played the game for 40 minutes (from that same save) I waited for the "saving" message, quit the game, and it loaded all the way back too 00:53:12 again... it's almost making me want to stop playing the game.

Anyone has had the same problem? I wish they would've just let you save like in past games, I hate it when they dumb games down, and even more so if it doesn't even work right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello this problem isn't very rare a lot of people suffer from this problem and others,
the game dose a lot of saves that don't work early in the game but for some reason it works a lot better
when you get to the town area i cant say for sure that will fix it but that is what i
learned so far so. the game dose a hard save when you enter a new location like in a building or a plot event
so far there is no fix for it sorry to say.